# R How to use which() with floating point values?

Tags: r

I have run into the same problem as described at [R which () function returns integer(0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34286905/r-which-function-returns-integer0)

```
price = seq(4,7, by=0.0025)
allPrices = as.data.frame(price)
lookupPrice = 5.0600
which(allPrices$price == lookupPrice)
```

The `which()` statement outputs `integer(0)`, indicating no match.  It should output 425, the matching row number in that sequence.

I understand that this is a floating point issue.  The link suggests using `all.equal(x,y)` in some manner.

How do I incorporate the `all.equal()` function into the `which()` statement, so that I get the row number in `allPrices` that matches `lookupPrice` (in this case, 5.06)?

Is there some other approach?  I need the row number, because values in other columns at that price will be modified.

Answer (score 2):

A manual approach to this involves specifying the tolerance for the comparison and doing:

```
# tol = 1e-7: comparison will be TRUE if numbers are equal up to 
#   7 decimal places
tol = 1e-7
which(abs(allPrices$price - lookupPrice) < tol)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `sapply` over all the prices and apply the `all.equal` function to each one, to find the one that is `TRUE`

```
which(sapply(price, all.equal, lookupPrice) == TRUE)
# [1] 425
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also try rounding the prices in your data frame to 4 decimal places:

```
which(round(allPrices$price, digits=4) == lookupPrice)
[1] 425
```

After rounding to 4 places, the precision of the `lookupPrice` and your data frame of prices should match.

## Demo

Comment: It may be necessary to apply `round()` to both sides.  My example code only showed one value.  My actual code has a sequence of values for `lookupPrice` which are processed in the a loop, so the floating point issue could be generated on either side of the `==` comparison.

Comment: @DougEdmunds Yes, I know this.  For the specific example you showed it is not necessary AFAIK though, and it would have made my answer more terse, so I left it out.

Comment: I also find that `round()` must be applied inside `which()` to work consistently.

Answer (score 1):

There is a function `near` in `dplyr`:

```
near(x, y, tol = .Machine$double.eps^0.5)
```

For this case, you can try:

```
which(near(allPrices$price, lookupPrice))
#[1] 425
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had the exact same problem.

I initially fixed it by converting both sets of data from numeric to characters with as.character() before calling which().

However, I wanted to figure out exactly why it wasn't working with the numeric data and did some further troubleshooting.

It appears that the problem is with the way R generates decimal sequences with seq(). Using the round() function works - as suggested by Tim Biegeleisen - but I think you only need to apply it to the numbers generated by seq(). You can check out my work below - the error is very sporadic, I just tried numbers until I found one that failed: 19.2.

```
> data <- 19.2
> x.seq <- seq(5, 45, 0.2)
> x.seq[72]
[1] 19.2
> 
> data == 19.2
[1] TRUE
> x.seq[72] == 19.2
[1] FALSE
> data == x.seq[72]
[1] FALSE
> data == round(x.seq[72], digits = 1)
[1] TRUE
> round(data, digits = 1) == x.seq[72]
[1] FALSE
```